# print page with css vuejs

Tags: html, vuejs2

I'm using vuejs ver2 on my application. I want to print the page using window.print() but the css is not getting. Thanks!

Here's my code

```
methods: {
    print: function (event) {
        var prtContent = document.getElementById("shipping-reservation-summary");
        var WinPrint = window.open('', '', 'left=0,top=0,width=800,height=900,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0');
        WinPrint.document.write(prtContent.innerHTML);
        WinPrint.document.close();
        WinPrint.focus();
        WinPrint.print();
        WinPrint.close();
    }
}
```